# Alloc MB / Sec vs Private Memory Size

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, performancecounter

I am working to reduce allocations in my application, and am tracking allocations using two variables.

The recommended way is to use the "Allocated Bytes/sec" performance counter, which updated every time there is a GC event (it is zero the rest of the time).

I was seeing numbers that were always in the 100's of megabytes per second, which didn't seem correct, so then I began checking `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` once per second and checking the difference (wont work at a GC, but gives a good idea), and I am seeing my expected 100kb - 1 mb per second of growth in the private memory size.

Why is the "Allocated Bytes/sec" returning numbers so much higher than the growth in the `PrivateMemorySize64` variable?